# Fundamental group of the circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, fundamental-groups

It is well known that the fundamental group of the circle is $\mathbb Z$. Why is this result given so much importance in math literature?

Over [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/42654/14875), one of the comments says, 'The fundamental group of the circle is Z. In my opinion this is one of the most consequential theorems in all of mathematics.'.

Comment: One consequence is the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: $B\mathbb Z$ being a $1$-dimensional simplicial set is also useful in group cohomology calculations.

Comment: It is a basic computation in algebraic topology, but the cited comment is way over the top and you should not take it as a universally accepted truth. Besides the comment, what evidence do you have to support the 2nd sentence?